# Cypress: login through magic link error with cy.origin()

Tags: authentication, email, cypress, cypress-origin

Devs at my startup have switched login to a magic link system, in which you get inside after clicking a link on the email body.

I have set up a Mailsac email to receive mails containing magic links but I haven't been able to actually follow those links because of the following:

[image]

```js
cy.request({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://mailsac.com/api/addresses/xxxx@mailsac.com/messages",
  headers: {
    "Mailsac-Key": "here-goes-the-key",
  },
}).then((res) => {
  const magicLink = res.body[0].links[0];
  cy.origin(magicLink, () => {
    cy.visit('/')
  });
});
```

I wasn't able to use cy.visit() either because the magic link URL is slightly different from the baseURL in this testing environment.

So my question is:
How could I follow this cumbersome link to find myself logged in home, or else, is there another way to deal with magic links?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please include your code and error as text within the question? Screenshots of code aren't very searchable ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say

> A URL specifying the secondary origin in which the callback is to be executed. This should at the very least contain a hostname, and may also include the protocol, port number & path. **Query params are not supported**.

Not sure if this means the `cy.visit()` argument should not have query params, of just the `cy.origin()` parameter.

Try passing in the link

```js
cy.request({
  ...
}).then((res) => {
  const magicLink = res.body[0].links[0];
  const magicOrigin = new URL(magicLink).origin
  cy.origin(magicOrigin, { args: { magicLink } }, ({ magicLink }) => {
    cy.visit(magicLink)
  });
});
```

If that doesn't fix it, you could try using `cy.request()` but you'll have to observe where the token is stored after using the magicLink.

```js
cy.request({
  ...
}).then((res) => {
  const magicLink = res.body[0].links[0];
  cy.request(magicLink).then(response =>
    const token = response???   // find out where the auth token ends up
    cy.setCookie(name, value)   // for example
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like the first suggestion is working, but its basically the same as Simon, and that for some reason gives me magicLink being undefined.
https://i.imgur.com/io6RKJV.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the domain as the first parameter to `origin`, and do the visit within the callback function, something like this:

```js
const magicLinkDomain = new Url(magicLink).hostname
cy.origin(magicLinkDomain, {args: magicLink}, ({ magicLink }) => {
    cy.visit(magicLink);
    //...
})
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Usage

Comment: That's what Im doing and having this error. Just added the code

Comment: The difference is that I'm not passing the magic link to cy.origin - I'm passing only the domain. You could extract this via something like `new Url(magicLink).hostname`.

Comment: Tried, but looks like everything inside cy.origin({}) is out of scope and cant use that magicLink variable inside it.

Comment: @user3303019, your error message says you can use the args parameter of cy.origin to pass the magicLink through. I've updated my answer to do this (the other answer to this question does this too).

Comment: Thanks, both are right, I was using it wrong. Glad to have this work out.